# IronPython and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ironpython

Has anyone built a website with IronPython and ASP.NET.  What were your experiences and is the combination ready for prime-time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current version of ASP.NET integration for IronPython is not very up-to-date and is more of a "proof-of-concept." I don't think I'd build a production website based on it.

**Edit:**: I have a very high level of expectation for how things like this should work, and might setting the bar a little high.  Maybe you should take what's in "ASP.NET Futures", write a test application for it and see how it works for you.  If you're successful, I'd like to hear about it.  Otherwise, I think there should be a newer CTP of this in the next six months.

(I'm a developer on IronPython and IronRuby.)

**Edit 2:** Since I originally posted this, a [newer version](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Dynamic%20Language%20Support) has been released.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Dynamic Languages in ASP.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Dynamic%20Language%20Support&referringTitle=Home) page on Codeplex. This has the newest IronPython bits. It doesn't give you any Visual Studio integration, other than the sample website project, but that's coming.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a look out for ASP.NET MVC

The IronRuby guys have got some internal builds of MVC to work with IronRuby, and IronPython 2 and IronRuby have a lot of code in common with the DLR.

I'm not sure if they'll support IronPython/IronRuby when MVC is released, but it's definitely worth keeping your eye on anyway - The old ASP.NET forms-based development model is old, busted, and the sooner it goes away the better.